# crystal reports - display mtd ytd lytd per family

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, crystal-reports

My report has 3 families (grouped by family.) I need to display the mtd, ytd, lytd per family AS:

```
household--mtd--ytd--lytd
family1     20   500 4000 
family2     300  70 6000 
family3     60  8880 977400
```

The only date field is called paiddate (datetime.)

If I use an `IF statement datedif("yyyy",-1,currentdate() then....` I get zeros for certain families due to the grouping. I think I may need a group selection formula or a new group for mtd, ytd and lytd?

Comment: mtd: month-to-date; ytd: year-to-date; lytd: ? long-year-to-date? If so, how is it defined?

Comment: all i have is the field paiddate as a datetime and field called paid, where i would like to calculate the mtd, ytd and lytd revenue.

Comment: Last Year To Date, maybe? From the beginning of last year to current date?

Comment: @user719825: **What do you mean** by "lytd"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create these formula fields and add them to your Details section.  Group and summarize as desired.

```
//{@MonthToDate}
If {table.paiddate} IN MonthToDate Then
  {table.revenue}
Else
  0

//{@YearToDate}
If {table.paiddate} IN YearToDate Then
  {table.revenue}
Else
  0

//{@OtherPeriodToDate}

//no clue what LYTD means; demonstrate a custom-range instead; substitute actual logic for Date(YYYY,MM,DD)
If {table.paiddate} IN Date(YYYY,MM,DD) TO Date(YYYY,MM,DD) Then
  {table.revenue}
Else
  0
```